# JPA and Hibernate NamedQuery Error: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have the below Hibernate NamedQuery that runs into issues when one of the "in" expressions has 1000 or more items.  When I have 1000 or more items in the ma.deviceId in (:devices), I get *java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000*

The only "in" expression that I need to take care of is the "and ma.deviceId in (:devices)".  Anyone have any ideas on how to rewrite this NamedQuery?  I'm using JPA and Hibernate.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Messages.findMessages", query = " SELECT ma from Messages ma JOIN FETCH ma.messagePayLoadXml mx LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH ma.messageProperties  mp " +
                  " WHERE ma.customerId = :customerId and ma.time >= :startTime and ma.time <= :endTime " +
                  " and ma.deviceId in (:devices) and  mx.messageType = 'XML' and mx.alerts in " +
                  " ( select mtfm.messageType from MessageTypeFeatureMap mtfm where mtfm.feature in (:featureType) ) " +
                  " and ma.messageKey = mx.messageKey and ( mp.deleted = 0 or mp.deleted is null ) " +
                  " order by ma.time desc " )
```

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=233143

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Oracle exception - "maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767920/java-oracle-exception-maximum-number-of-expressions-in-a-list-is-1000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways.
1) Store your list in intermediary table and do
`... IN (SELECT ... FROM intermediaryTable)`
2) Break your list into sublists each upto 1000 elements and write your query as
`(... IN (subList1) OR ... IN (subList2) ...)`

Comment: Is there any way to increase the list allocation size in JPA ?

Comment: No, because it is NOT JPA limitation. The limit is imposed be SQL databases.

Answer (score 1):

For our application we have done a simple fix for this situation...

```
 If number of values are greater than 999
      QUERY = SELECT + FROM + WHERE + COND1 +
              ( FIELD IN ( 999 values ) OR FIELD IN ( 999 values )...)  + ORDER
 Else
      QUERY = SELECT + FROM + WHERE + COND1 + IN (...) + ORDER
```