# Most efficient way to deal with ORA-01795:maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 in hibernate

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

I have to perform a select on which I have more than 1000 elements via hibernate, and then I received the error "ORA-01795:maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000" when I'm using the Oracle brand.

```
SELECT * FROM matable WHERE column IN (?,?,...) (>1000 items)
```

I found many solutions : 
Split the list with OR

> ```
> where A in (a,b,c,d,e,f)
> ```
>
> becomes
>
> ```
> where (A in (a,b,c) OR a in (d,e,f)) ...
> ```

Create a table with UNION ALL

> ```
> SELECT * FROM maintable
> JOIN (
>     SELECT v1 a FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>     SELECT v2 a FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>     SELECT v3 a FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>     ...
>     SELECT v2000 a FROM DUAL) tmp
>
>     on tmp.a = maintable.id
> ```

Using tuples to get rid of the limit

> `where (column,0) in ((1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0), ... ,(1500,0))`

Using a temporary table..

> ```
> where A in SELECT item FROM my_temporary_table
> ```

References [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253851/ora-01795-maximum-number-of-expressions-in-a-list-is-1000) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682646/caused-by-java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01795-maximum-number-of-expressions-in-a) and also [there](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1089625).

My question is the following : what is the best practice to deal with this issue? By best practice I mean the most performant, but not only for Oracle;  if I use hibernate, I don't want to create and manage a different code for each brand of database (I'm concerned by Oracle, MS SQL and PostGre only).

My first reaction would have been to use a temporary table, but I don't know what has the most impact.

Comment: My gut reaction would be the temporary table too. However, you have the data, you have the code; what's stopping you from testing this yourself and finding which one works fastest for your particular scenario?

Comment: You're right I could do the test (and probably will), but I would also like to understand how the database does handle/optimize each type of query, and what is less/more expensive.

Answer (score 4):

Use a temporary table and make the values primary keys on the table.  This should allow very efficient optimizations for comparison.  The most like is simply an index lookup, although if the table is very small, Oracle might choose some other method such as a table scan.

This method should be faster than 1,000 `or` conditions, in almost any database.  Sometimes `in` is optimized in a similar way (using a binary tree to store the values).  In such databases, the performance would be similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So that means that values in a "IN" statement are stored in something similar to an index that would be in-memory, and tested one by one with an OR statement? 

If I use OR, I would not use 1000 or conditions, but rather n lists of 1000 elements linked by an OR.

Comment: I'm voting up this answer, moreover I would suggest to create this table as an Index-Organized table, so that rows are organized in PK order and PK and index are not duplicated, because they are internally stored in the one place

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I didn't knew the existence of Index-Organized table.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue with some changes in hibernate-core jar.

I made a helper class to split an expression in more joins like: `... t.column IN (: list_1) OR t.column IN (: list_2) ...` , Then I changed AbstractQueryImpl.expandParameterList method  from hibernate to call my method if the collection exceeds the limit. 
My hibernate-core version is 3.6.10.Final, but it work fine and for 4.x versions - I tested it. 
My code is tested for next cases:

```
  where t.id in (:idList)
  where (t.id in (:idList))
  where ((t.id) in (:idList))
  where 1=1 and t.id in (:idList)
  where 1=1 and (t.id in (:idList))
  where 1=1 and(t.id) in (:idList)
  where 1=1 and((t.id) in (:idList))
  where 1=1 and(t.id in (:idList))

  where t.id not in (:idList)
  where (t.id not in (:idList))
  where ((t.id) not in (:idList))
```

AbstractQueryImpl.expandParameterList :

```
private String expandParameterList(String query, String name, TypedValue typedList, Map namedParamsCopy) {
    Collection vals = (Collection) typedList.getValue();
    Type type = typedList.getType();

    boolean isJpaPositionalParam = parameterMetadata.getNamedParameterDescriptor( name ).isJpaStyle();
    String paramPrefix = isJpaPositionalParam ? "?" : ParserHelper.HQL_VARIABLE_PREFIX;
    String placeholder =
            new StringBuffer( paramPrefix.length() + name.length() )
                    .append( paramPrefix ).append(  name )
                    .toString();

    if ( query == null ) {
        return query;
    }
    int loc = query.indexOf( placeholder );

    if ( loc < 0 ) {
        return query;
    }

    String beforePlaceholder = query.substring( 0, loc );
    String afterPlaceholder =  query.substring( loc + placeholder.length() );

    // check if placeholder is already immediately enclosed in parentheses
    // (ignoring whitespace)
    boolean isEnclosedInParens =
            StringHelper.getLastNonWhitespaceCharacter( beforePlaceholder ) == '(' &&
                    StringHelper.getFirstNonWhitespaceCharacter( afterPlaceholder ) == ')';

    if ( vals.size() == 1  && isEnclosedInParens ) {
        // short-circuit for performance when only 1 value and the
        // placeholder is already enclosed in parentheses...
        namedParamsCopy.put( name, new TypedValue( type, vals.iterator().next(), session.getEntityMode() ) );
        return query;
    }

    // *** changes by Vasile Bors for HHH-1123 ***
    // case vals.size() > 1000
    if ((vals.size() >= InExpressionExpander.MAX_ALLOWED_PER_INEXPR) && isEnclosedInParens) {

        InExpressionExpander inExpressionExpander = new InExpressionExpander(beforePlaceholder, afterPlaceholder);
        if(inExpressionExpander.isValidInOrNotInExpression()){

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>( vals.size() );
            Iterator iter = vals.iterator();
            int i = 0;
            String alias;
            while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
                alias = ( isJpaPositionalParam ? 'x' + name : name ) + i++ + '_';
                namedParamsCopy.put( alias, new TypedValue( type, iter.next(), session.getEntityMode() ) );
                list.add(ParserHelper.HQL_VARIABLE_PREFIX + alias );
            }

            String expandedExpression = inExpressionExpander.expandExpression(list);
            if(expandedExpression != null){
                return expandedExpression;
            }
        }
    }
    // *** end changes by Vasile Bors for HHH-1123 ***

    StringBuffer list = new StringBuffer(16);
    Iterator iter = vals.iterator();
    int i = 0;
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String alias = (isJpaPositionalParam ? 'x' + name : name) + i++ + '_';
        namedParamsCopy.put(alias, new TypedValue(type, iter.next(), session.getEntityMode()));
        list.append(ParserHelper.HQL_VARIABLE_PREFIX).append(alias);
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            list.append(", ");
        }
    }

    return StringHelper.replace(
            beforePlaceholder,
            afterPlaceholder,
            placeholder.toString(),
            list.toString(),
            true,
            true
    );
}
```

My helper class InExpressionExpander:

package org.hibernate.util;

```
import org.hibernate.QueryException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * Utility class for expand Hql and Sql IN expressions with a parameter with more than IN expression limit size (HHH-1123).
 * <br/>
 * It work for expression with formats:
 * <pre>
 *
 * where t.id in (:idList)
 * where (t.id in (:idList))
 * where ((t.id) in (:idList))
 * where 1=1 and t.id in (:idList)
 * where 1=1 and (t.id in (:idList))
 * where 1=1 and(t.id) in (:idList)
 * where 1=1 and((t.id) in (:idList))
 * where 1=1 and(t.id in (:idList))
 *
 * where t.id not in (:idList)
 * where (t.id not in (:idList))
 * where ((t.id) not in (:idList))
 * </pre>
 * <p/>
 * Example:
 * <pre>
 * select t.id from tableOrEntity t where t.id IN (:idList)
 * </pre
 *
 * @author Vasile Bors
 * @since 13/12/2015.
 */
public class InExpressionExpander {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InExpressionExpander.class);

    public static final  int MAX_ALLOWED_PER_INEXPR = 1000;
    private static final int MAX_PARAMS_PER_INEXPR  = 500;

    private Stack<String> stackExpr = new Stack<String>();
    private StringBuilder toWalkQuery;

    private final String beforePlaceholder;
    private final String afterPlaceholder;
    private boolean wasChecked         = false;
    private boolean isEnclosedInParens = false;
    private boolean isInExpr           = false;
    private boolean isNotInExpr        = false;

    public InExpressionExpander(String beforePlaceholder, String afterPlaceholder) {
        this.toWalkQuery = new StringBuilder(beforePlaceholder);

        this.beforePlaceholder = beforePlaceholder;
        this.afterPlaceholder = afterPlaceholder;
    }

    public boolean isValidInOrNotInExpression() {
        if (!wasChecked) {
            String lastExpr = extractLastExpression();
            if ("(".equals(lastExpr)) {
                isEnclosedInParens = true;
                lastExpr = extractLastExpression();
            }
            isInExpr = "in".equalsIgnoreCase(lastExpr);
        }

        wasChecked = true;
        return isInExpr;
    }

    public String expandExpression(List paramList) {
        if (isValidInOrNotInExpression()) {

            final String lastExpr = extractLastExpression(false);

            if ("not".equalsIgnoreCase(lastExpr)) {
                isNotInExpr = true;
                extractLastExpression(); //extract "not" and consume it
            }

            extractColumnForInExpression();

            StringBuilder exprPrefixBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = stackExpr.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                exprPrefixBuilder.append(stackExpr.get(i)).append(' ');
            }
            if (!isEnclosedInParens) {
                exprPrefixBuilder.append('(');
            }

            String expandedExpression = expandInExpression(exprPrefixBuilder, paramList);
            String beforeExpression = getBeforeExpression();
            String afterExpression = getAfterExpression();

            String expandedQuery = new StringBuilder(beforeExpression).append(expandedExpression)
                    .append(afterExpression)
                    .toString();

            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug(
                        "Query was changed to prevent exception for maximum number of expression in a list. Expanded IN expression query:\n {}",
                        expandedExpression);

                log.debug("Expanded query:\n {}", expandedQuery);
            }

            return expandedQuery;
        }

        log.error("Illegal call of InExpressionExpander.expandExpression() without IN expression.");
        return null;
    }

    private String expandInExpression(StringBuilder exprPrefixBuilder, List values) {

        String joinExpr = isNotInExpr ? ") and " : ") or ";
        StringBuilder expr = new StringBuilder(16);
        Iterator iter = values.iterator();
        int i = 0;
        boolean firstExpr = true;
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            if (firstExpr || i % MAX_PARAMS_PER_INEXPR == 0) {
                //close previous expression and start new expression
                if (!firstExpr) {
                    expr.append(joinExpr);
                } else {
                    firstExpr = false;
                }
                expr.append(exprPrefixBuilder);
            } else {
                expr.append(", ");
            }
            expr.append(iter.next());
            i++;
        }

        expr.append(')');// close for last in expression

        return expr.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Method extract last expression parsed by space from toWalkQuery and remove it from toWalkQuery;<br/>
     * If expression has brackets it will return al content between brackets and it will add additional space to adjust splitting by space.
     *
     * @return last expression from toWalkQuery
     */
    private String extractLastExpression() {
        return extractLastExpression(true);
    }

    /**
     * Method extract last expression parsed by space from toWalkQuery, remove it from toWalkQuery if is consume = true;<br/>
     * If expression has brackets it will return al content between brackets and it will add additional space to adjust splitting by space.
     *
     * @param consum if true  the method will extract and remove last expression from toWalkQuery
     * @return last expression from toWalkQuery
     */
    private String extractLastExpression(final boolean consum) {
        int lastIndex = this.toWalkQuery.length() - 1;
        String lastExpr;
        int exprSeparatorIndex = this.toWalkQuery.lastIndexOf(" ");
        if (lastIndex == exprSeparatorIndex) { //remove last space from the end
            this.toWalkQuery.delete(exprSeparatorIndex, this.toWalkQuery.length());
            return extractLastExpression(consum);
        } else {
            lastExpr = this.toWalkQuery.substring(exprSeparatorIndex + 1, this.toWalkQuery.length());

            if (lastExpr.length() > 1) {
                if (lastExpr.endsWith(")")) {
                    //if parens are closed at the end we need to find where it is open
                    int opensParens = 0;
                    int closedParens = 0;
                    int startExprIndex = -1;

                    char c;
                    for (int i = lastExpr.length() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                        c = lastExpr.charAt(i);
                        if (c == ')') {
                            closedParens++;
                        } else if (c == '(') {
                            opensParens++;
                        }

                        if (closedParens == opensParens) {
                            startExprIndex = i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (startExprIndex > -1) {
                        lastExpr = lastExpr.substring(startExprIndex, lastExpr.length());
                        exprSeparatorIndex = exprSeparatorIndex + startExprIndex
                                + 1; // +1 because separator is not space and don't must be deleted
                    }
                } else if (lastExpr.contains("(")) {
                    int parentsIndex = exprSeparatorIndex + lastExpr.indexOf('(') + 1;
                    this.toWalkQuery.replace(parentsIndex, parentsIndex + 1, " ( ");
                    return extractLastExpression(consum);
                }
            }

            if (consum) {
                this.toWalkQuery.delete(exprSeparatorIndex, this.toWalkQuery.length());
            }
        }

        if (consum) {
            stackExpr.push(lastExpr);
        }

        return lastExpr;
    }

    private String extractColumnForInExpression() {
        String column = extractLastExpression();

        String beforeColumn = extractLastExpression(false);
        long pointIndx = beforeColumn.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (pointIndx > -1) {
            if (pointIndx == (beforeColumn.length() - 1)) {
                throw new QueryException(
                        "Invalid column format: " + beforeColumn + ' ' + column
                                + " . Remove space from column!");
            }
        }
        return column;
    }

    private String getBeforeExpression() {
        return this.toWalkQuery + " (";
    }

    private String getAfterExpression() {
        if (StringHelper.getFirstNonWhitespaceCharacter(afterPlaceholder) == ')') {
            return afterPlaceholder;
        }
        return afterPlaceholder + ") ";
    }
}
```

I am happy to receive any suggestions for improving this solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10806700)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.